# 'Check' to refer train/u-bahn platform?

Tags: meaning

I was just in Berlin and heard people refer to the train/U-bahn platform as 'check' when speaking English ('We meet at the check', 'the train will depart from check 2'). As far as I know, this is not used in English to refer to a platform. Is it a word used in German that people assume is also English? I also find this unlikely as in German they always used Gleis. Therefore I am very curious as to where this use of 'check' comes from and cannot find it using google or dictionaries. Hopefully someone here knows.

Comment: Any chance it was "Steig"? "Bahnsteig" is a common term.

Comment: @Robert     First I thought this is a good guess, but then: those people allegedly spoke English, so how would *Steig* appear in their utterances  as probably *platform* is relatively well-known?

Comment: Maybe *checkpoint*, referring to the old Berlin Wall checkpoints was meant?

Comment: Maybe a pub named *Check-In* was meant? It's a not too-uncommon name, and some pub owners open another store and call it *Check-In 2*.

Comment: Any idea what the native languages of those people might have been?

Comment: It was said at Berlin Hbf., announcing departing international trains, so I do not think they meant a pub :P Announcing these trains in German they used Gleis. At first I thought maybe they said 'track', but listening carefully it did not sound like that. And then german colleagues told us to meet at the check, pretty sure they meant meet at the platform and not on the train tracks.

Comment: @Carsten: I would suppose: Czech!

Comment: @Anne. I am confused. First I thought you were referring to ordinary people talking about where to meet. From your comment I believe to understand that this was some announcement by the railway station staff?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, it was both.

Comment: @Anne.  Remarkable. Perhaps you stumbled upon coded communication of security personnel in the station?

Comment: Actually, I think that *track* is a good theory. R's are difficult.

Comment: @Carsten   The loudspeaker announcement being acoustically distorted, and then passengers mocking it by imitating it?

Comment: The english word is not check, there is no german word check or similar to it. This question might only lead to wild speculations, most probably not to a definitivly correct answer. I vote to close it as unclear, what is asked. An audio file of the announcing could probably fix the problem, but most likely it isn't about the german language at all.

Comment: This is not a question about the german language.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: It is a question about German vocabulary used in context, and thus fully on-topic. If anything, I somewhat share user unknown's concerns about being definitely able to tell what the OP heard.

Comment: @Anne, to be clearly on-topic, you may want to edit your question to explicitly state you are looking for a **term used in German** that would make German native speakers likely to use the English word *check* when referring to a platform.

Comment: Generally I think that questions asking which feature of the German language may have caused a particular mistake that a native German speaker has made in English can be on topic.

Answer (score 4):

It is pretty likely they were saying **track**. If the speakers were not native English speakers, there may well have been some mispronunciation of the English *R* sound and the English *A*.

In German, it's not normally the *Bahnsteig* (platform) that is numbered, but the *Gleis* (railroad track). Likewise, at least in everyday language, there is only one *Bahnsteig* between a pair of *Gleise* (in the case of a the platform being in the middle), so counting just the *Bahnsteige* is less precise than counting the *Gleise*.

The OP writes in a comment:

> And then german colleagues told us to meet at the check, pretty sure they meant meet at the platform and not on the train tracks.

I consider this to support my point, as "[sich] am Gleis [treffen]" is a usual way to indicate the platform as a meeting location in German<sup>1</sup>.

Therefore, the answer is: **No, there is no word like *Check* used in German to refer to a platform or track.**

<sup>1</sup>: Note that in German train systems, passengers can usually stay on the platform for any amount of time (i.e. there is no expectation for them to board the very next train that arrives). In most of these systems (in particular, long-distance trains, which would be the subject of the described "announc[ement of] departing international trains"), people may enter the platform at any time and without any tickets, making the area on the platform next to a track a suitable spot for gathering as a group.